# Como testar um "await import" com o Jest no TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jest

Tenho uma api que no arquivo que faz a importação das rotas para então vinculá-las ao app do express eu uso o fast-glob para procurar por arquivos com a extensão `*.route.ts` e então importar esses métodos, assim:

**`app.ts`** (arquivo onde está o servidor do express)

```js
import express from 'express'
import setupRoutes from './routes'

const app = express()

setupRoutes(app)

export default app
```

**`routes.ts`** (arquivo onde faço a importação dinâmica das rotas)

```js
import { Express, Router } from 'express'
import fg from 'fast-glob'

export default (app: Express): void => {
  const router = Router()
  app.use('/api', router)
  fg.sync('**/src/routes/**route.ts')
    .map(async file => (await import(`../../../${file}`)).default(router))
}
```

**`routes/sample.route.ts`** (um arquivo de exemplo de uma rota qualquer)

```js
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'

export default (router: Router): void => {
  router.post('/sample', (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('sample!')
  })
}
```

Meu problema é que ao verificar a cobertura do meu código eu não consigo verificar a linha 9 do arquivo **`routes.ts`** que é onde eu faço um map e então um import dos arquivos, chamando a função default e passando o router (como podem ver nos exemplos acima).

Preciso saber como posso verificar essa linha visto que tenho que validar os import's. A intenção é melhorar a cobertura do códigp. Eu sei que posso forçar o jest a ignorar esse arquivo mas não é uma boa prática... Hoje o arquivo de testes para as rotas está assim:

**`__tests__/route.test.ts`** (arquivo de testes para o arquivo de rotas)

```js
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fast-glob'
import setupRoutes from '../routes'

describe('routes', () => {
  it('should call fast-glob.sync to search all route files', () => {
    const syncSpy = jest.spyOn(fs, 'sync')
    const app = express()
    setupRoutes(app)
    expect(syncSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: Cara, sendo franco com você, não tem porque testar o `await import`. Você precisa simplesmente confiar que eles funcionam, já que são parte da linguagem. :-) Utilize o comentário mágico `/* istanbul ignore next */` para impedir que essa linha apareça no _report_ de coverage e seja feliz.

Comment: A intenção não é exatamente testar isso mas sim se os imports dinâmicos estão corretos, pra chegar a ter 100% de cobertura